# Verilog. Multidimensional array initialization

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I create localparam in my simulation-only SystemVerilog module:

```
   localparam [31:0] SYNTH_PRD_REGS[1][5][13] = '{
                 '{
  '{32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000},
  '{32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000},
  '{32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000},
  '{32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000},
  '{32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000,32'h00000000}                             
                }
 }; // Error for this line.
```

I compile this module, but when I start simulation, error expected:

> RUNTIME: Fatal Error: RUNTIME_0123 tb_bus.sv (35): Range width
>   expression must be positive.

Why this error occurs? I use Active -HDL 9.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can u try with this thing:

```
localparam [31:0] SYNTH_PRD_REGS[5][13] = '{default:32'h0}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a tool issue. Your code is fine and works on many other tools.

Comment: And what is this? How I may initialize this array in another way?

Comment: Your tool has a bug. I don't have access to your tool, so I can't help with a workaround.